# How to convert const void* to unsigned int?

Tags: c++, lua

So in this code:

```
unsigned int lptr = lua_topointer(L, -1);
```

It gives the error:
cannot convert from 'const void *' to 'unsigned int'

I have tried reinterpret_cast to convert it like this:

```
unsigned int lptr = reinterpret_cast<const void*>(lua_topointer(L, -1)));
```

but it gives me another error that says this:
a value of type "const void*" cannot be used to initilize an entity of type "unsigned int"

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Are you trying to get the integer value of the address so that you can print it?

Answer (score 3):

`lua_topointer` returns a `void const*`.  Your `reinterpret_cast` isn't actually changing anything.  What you need to write is:

```
unsigned int value = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(lua_topointer(L, -1)));
```

But bear in mind that this will only work on platforms  where the size of an `int` happens to match the size of a pointer.  It's better to use `std::uintptr_t` from `<cstdint>` instead since the size is guaranteed to match.

```
std::uintptr_t value = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(lua_topointer(L, -1)));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you mean by converting a void pointer to an integer. If you intend to access the pointed object, then see the documentation of `lua_topointer`:

> Converts the value at the given acceptable index to a generic C pointer (void*). The value can be a userdata, a table, a thread, or a function; otherwise, lua_topointer returns NULL. Different objects will give different pointers. **There is no way to convert the pointer back to its original value.**
>
> Typically this function is used only for debug information.

Also note that according to the quoted documentation, the pointed object cannot be an `unsigned int`.

---

If you instead intend to represent the pointer as an integer, first I suggest that you consider *why* would you want to do that. It's not typically needed. Most reasonable things that can be done with the integer representation such as printing can be done with the pointer itself directly.

But if you *really* want to "convert" a pointer to an integer, `unsigned int` is not a good choice since it is not guaranteed to be able to represent all values that can be represented by a data pointer.`std::uintptr_t` can represent all such values and this would be correct way to convert:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(data_pointer)
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` of a pointer to an integral type of equal or greater size is also correct (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: @PeterRuderman good point. I shan't suggest using memcpy then.